# proper alignment with bootstrap horizontal forms

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code as shown in the bootstrap site for horizontal forms. I have included the bootstrap.css file necessary. However my horizontal forms are not aligning as expected. The labels are at the extreme left and the forms start from 25% of browser margin and extend till end of page horizontally and the forms touch each other above and below without any spacing.

The bootstrap page says about using the .form-horizontal class but I am clueless as to where should I use it. Help will be appreciated. Pasting my code below.

```
<form role="form" class=".form_horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category_type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_type" placeholder="Select a category">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project_title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_title" placeholder="Enter Title here">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quarter" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quarter/Year</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quarter" placeholder="Enter Quarter here Eg. Q2,2013">
                </div>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project_description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="project_description" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Description here"></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contributors" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contributors</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contriutors" placeholder="Contributors">
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can u reproduce the same here ? http://jsbin.com/ACAQEqAS/1/

Comment: This is the same I see in my browser! The labels need to close enough to the form boxes and there should be some padding between them vertically and I want to change their width's according to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe this:

```
  <form role="form" class=".form_horizontal">
```

Should be changed to this

```
   <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
```

The classname looks odd for bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

the problem was `<form role="form" class=".form_horizontal">`

It should be `<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">`